# When document.readystate==complete is that the same when onload fires?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

In Internet Explorer, when `onreadystatechange` is fired, and `readystate` switches to complete, is that the same time `onload` event triggers? Have all the requests completed by this time?

Comment: perhaps if you tell us how you want to use it we can suggest best practice, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.onreadystatechange` is typically more optimal than `window.onload` as it fires before all external resources such as images are loaded. However, it's not well supported at the moment (but if you're only concerned with IE, then it's not a problem).

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.onreadystatechange

Or, for IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536957(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Where do you find the browser support for `readyState` and its 3 possible values?

Answer (score 2):

`document.readyState`  is a property and `window.onload` is an event

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp

Comment: sorry I did not clarify my question. The question is mroe when readystate switches to complete, is that when onload also fires.

Comment: JavaScript is not multi-threaded so events are fired in sequential manner; for which will fire first you will have to test it in major browsers to be sure

Comment: Tested it on IE8 and IE7, OnreadyStateChange with on ReadyState==complete fires about 30-60ms before onload. They both wait for everything on the page to load.